# Strange Audit LOG entry

Tags: audit, rhel7

One of the processes running on a RHEL 7.2 server (process name: billsrv) is terminating randomly, after receiving a kill -9 command.
I used the audit log to identify who is sending the kill -9 command:
First I killed it manualy. In the audit file I got the following:

```
*Nov 26 19:09:05 coscms1 audispd: node=coscms1 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1543252145.658:639488): 
arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=2b88 a1=12 a2=2b88 a3=2b88 items=0 
ppid=16150 pid=16151 auid=400 uid=400 gid=400 euid=400 suid=400 fsuid=400 egid=400 sgid=400 fsgid=400 tty=pts4 
ses=89169 comm="ksh" exe="/usr/bin/ksh93" key="kill_signals"*
```

Then after some time the billsrv process killed and I got the following in the Audit file:

```
Nov 26 20:10:28 coscms1 audispd: node=coscms1 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1543255828.282:642321): 
arch=c000003e syscall=62 success=yes exit=0 a0=5ceb a1=9 a2=5ceb a3=7f3e8dd23cf0 items=0 
ppid=29836 pid=23796 auid=400 uid=400 gid=400 euid=400 suid=400 fsuid=400 egid=400 sgid=400 fsgid=400 tty=(none) 
ses=89169 comm="billsrv" exe="/users/cms/bin/billsrv" key="kill_signals"
```

Does the above mean that the process killed itself ? (!!!)

Comment: Check in the kernel log (`/var/log/messages`) - perhaps it was the OOM killer, which would mean that you ran out of memory.

Comment: Already checked that. There is nothing in /var/log/messages. In terms of memory resources, machine was using at that time less than 30% of the available memory. Thanks for replying anyway!

Answer (score 0):

My process was receiving a kill signal from the oracle 12 client(!) 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3567492
We disabled the “diagnostic Framework” on client level and everything looks OK.